# Named Entity Recognition using NLTK: Extract Auditor name, address and organisation

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to use nltk to identify Person, Organization and Place from a sentence.

My Use Case is to basically extract Auditor name, organization and Place from an annual financial report

With nltk in python the results don't seem to be really satisfactory

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.tag import pos_tag

ex='Alastair John Richard Nuttall (Senior statutory auditor) for and on behalf of Ernst & Young LLP (Statutory auditor) Leeds'

ne_tree = ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(ex)))

print(ne_tree)

Tree('S', [Tree('PERSON', [('Alastair', 'NNP')]), Tree('PERSON', [('John', 'NNP'), ('Richard', 'NNP'), ('Nuttall', 'NNP')]), ('(', '('), Tree('ORGANIZATION', [('Senior', 'NNP')]), ('statutory', 'NNP'), ('auditor', 'NN'), (')', ')'), ('for', 'IN'), ('and', 'CC'), ('on', 'IN'), ('behalf', 'NN'), ('of', 'IN'), Tree('GPE', [('Ernst', 'NNP')]), ('&', 'CC'), Tree('PERSON', [('Young', 'NNP'), ('LLP', 'NNP')]), ('(', '('), ('Statutory', 'NNP'), ('auditor', 'NN'), (')', ')'), ('Leeds', 'NNS')])
```

As seen above 'Leeds' is not identified as place nor is Ernst & Young LLP recognized as Organization

Are there any better ways of achieving this in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try spacy instead of NLTK:

https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#named-entities

I think spacy's pretrained models are likely to perform better. The results (with spacy 2.1, en_core_web_lg) for your sentence are:

> Alastair John Richard Nuttall PERSON
>   Ernst & Young LLP ORG
>   Leeds GPE

Comment: Thanks. Will we able to load this model on a non-GPU machine though?